# Trying to print all TR elements and all TD elements from a web page

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am playing around with the script below and trying to get it to write all TR elements and all TD elements from a web page into a CSV file.  For some unknown reason, I'm getting no data, at all, in the CSV file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

url = "https://my_url"
page = requests.get(url)
pagetext = page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(pagetext, 'html.parser')

file = open("C:/my_path/test.csv", 'w')

for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
        print(col.text)
```

I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: Your code works fine. I've tested it on this [page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). Try to check the html source of your website. Maybe the problem is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your url is not a website so it won't be able to find anything. You just need to fix the url and try again.

I have fixed the code so that you can finish it. It will only add the first line of data in the list to the csv file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

url = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp"
page = requests.get(url)
pagetext = page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(pagetext, 'html.parser')

file = open("C:/Test/test2.csv", 'w')

for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
        info= col.text
        print(info)


file.write(info)
file.close()
```

Comment: I don't know what's going on here, but it doesn't work for me.  The code runs without any kind of error, but it doesn't write anything to the CSV file.  
I just tried it on this link: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp'.  I got nothing at all.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the entire code that I ran and had it work perfectly.

Comment: Yes, it prints everything in the console window but it doesn't write to the csv file.  That's my problem.

Comment: I have solved the issue and am going to update my code

Comment: Try `file.close()` instead. Or better yet use a `with` statement.

Comment: Also, `file.write(info)` should be inside the loop

Comment: Ah yes!!  Now I see how it works!!  Thanks so much!!